# JavaScript or Jquery event handlers for “ctrl” + change

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

Every time (with or without <kbd>CTRL</kbd> press), I am getting the same log; `control is not pressed`. Can someone please explain what is the reason.

```
$("Selector").on("change",function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey){
        console.log("ctrl is pressed");
    }
    else{
        console.log("ctrl is not pressed");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the change event does not contain keyboard information. To do this you would need to set a flag on a parent element which is set on keydown of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key and check for that flag being true when the change event occurs

Something like this:

```
var ctrlKeyHeld = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    ctrlKeyHeld = e.ctrlKey;
}).keyup(function() {
    ctrlKeyHeld = false;
})

$("#foo").on("change",function(e){
    if (ctrlKeyHeld){
        console.log("ctrl is pressed");
    }
    else{
        console.log("ctrl is not pressed");
    }
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/yr0xrcpn/)

Comment: You should still check than the released key is the Ctrl one: `.keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 17) ctrlKeyHeld = false;
})`